# Cannot GET Error when running HTML on Node

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link in my home html, but when clicking on it, it gets the error :

> Cannot GET /Forgot_Password_V1.html

```
Directory:
-Login_Page_V2.html
-Forgot_Password_V1.html
-Login_Page_V1.js
```

```js
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//routes
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/Login_Page_V2.html'));
});

app.get('/Forgot_Password_V1', function(request, response) {
response.sendFile(__dirname + './Forgot_Password_V1.html');
});
```

```html
<a href="Forgot_Password_V1.html" style="text-decoration: none">Forgot your password?</a>
```

I've also tried this HTML but didn't work:

```
<a href="http://<server_url>/Forgot_Password_V1.html" style="text-decoration: none">Forgot your password?</a>
```

Comment: Is this express? `/Forgot_Password_V1` gets matched instead of `/Forgot_Password_V1.html`.  The static option should be used for serving static files: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Typo: Your route is `/Forgot_Password_V1` but your URL is `/Forgot_Password_V1.html`. The extra 5 characters on the end stop it matching the route.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to render it? Are you injecting any content or updating it on the fly. If not you can directly send it as below.

```
app.get('/Forgot_Password_V1', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + 'Forgot_Password_V1.html');
})
```